# Using Pandas to calculate distance between coordinates from imported csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I am trying to import a .csv that contains two columns of location data (lat/long), compute the distance between points, write the distance to a new column, loop the function to the next set of coordinates, and write the output data frame to a new .csv.  I have the following code written and it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.read_csv("input.csv")

def dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
R = 6371  # Earth radius in km

#conversion to radians
d_lat = np.radians(lat2-lat1)
d_lon = np.radians(lon2-lon1)

r_lat1 = np.radians(lat1)
r_lat2 = np.radians(lat2)

#haversine formula
a = np.sin(d_lat/2.) **2 + np.cos(r_lat1) * np.cos(r_lat2) * np.sin(d_lon/2.)**2

haversine = 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

return haversine

lat1 = row['lat1'] #first row of location.lat column here
lon1 = row['lon1'] #first row of location.long column here
lat2 = row['lat2'] #second row of location.lat column here
lon2 = row['lon2'] #second row of location.long column here

print(dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2), 'km')

df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I am receiving the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 22, in 
    lat1 = row['lat1'] #first row of location.lat column here
NameError: name 'row' is not defined

Could additional feedback be provided on how to successfully loop this formula through this data?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Forget my previous comment. Have you tried printing `line` and see what it actually contains? It seems to be a list with more than the 3 fields you assume.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are using 4 columns in your input.csv which contains the value of lat1,lon1,lat2 and lon2. So, after going through the operation, the output.csv file is a separate file which contains all the previous 4 columns as well as the 5th column which is the distance. You can use a for loop to do this. The method that I am showing here reads each row and calculates the distance and append it in an empty list which is the new column "Distance" and eventually creates output.csv. Make changes anywhere necessary. **Remember that this works on 4 columns csv file with multiple coordinates value**. Hope that this helps you. Have a great day.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
input_file = "input.csv"
output_file = "output.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)                       #Dataframe specification
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)

def dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
  R = 6371  # Earth radius in km

  #conversion to radians
  d_lat = np.radians(lat2-lat1)
  d_lon = np.radians(lon2-lon1)

  r_lat1 = np.radians(lat1)
  r_lat2 = np.radians(lat2)

  #haversine formula
  a = np.sin(d_lat/2.) **2 + np.cos(r_lat1) * np.cos(r_lat2) * np.sin(d_lon/2.)**2

  haversine = 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

  return haversine

new_column = []                    #empty column for distance
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  lat1 = row['lat1'] #first row of location.lat column here
  lon1 = row['lon1'] #first row of location.long column here
  lat2 = row['lat2'] #second row of location.lat column here
  lon2 = row['lon2'] #second row of location.long column here
  value = dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)  #get the distance
  new_column.append(value)   #append the empty list with distance values

df.insert(4,"Distance",new_column)  #4 is the index where you want to place your column. Column index starts with 0. "Distance" is the header and new_column are the values in the column.

with open(output_file,'ab') as f:
  df.to_csv(f,index = False)       #creates the output.csv
```