# How to use Python to calculate the distance between lat/long points from imported csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, haversine

I am trying to import a .csv that contains four columns of location data (lat/long), compute the distance between points, write the distance to a new column, loop the function to the next set of coordinates, and write the output data frame to a new .csv. I have the following code written and it. **I am getting an error after going through these steps.**

**Example Data:**

```
lat1       lon1        lat2       lon2
33.58144   -57.73018   32.44873   -99.46281
25.46212   -46.62017   34.64971   -96.70271
39.97521   -80.27027   68.69710   -83.27182
42.74529   -73.73028   36.17318   -28.18201
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
input_file = "input.csv"
output_file = "output.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)                       #Dataframe specification
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)

def dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
  R = 6371  # Earth radius in km

  #conversion to radians
  d_lat = np.radians(lat2-lat1)
  d_lon = np.radians(lon2-lon1)

  r_lat1 = np.radians(lat1)
  r_lat2 = np.radians(lat2)

  #haversine formula
  a = np.sin(d_lat/2.) **2 + np.cos(r_lat1) * np.cos(r_lat2) * np.sin(d_lon/2.)**2

  haversine = 2 * R * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))

  return haversine

new_column = []                    #empty column for distance
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  lat1 = row['lat1'] #first row of location.lat column here
  lon1 = row['lon1'] #first row of location.long column here
  lat2 = row['lat2'] #second row of location.lat column here
  lon2 = row['lon2'] #second row of location.long column here
  value = dist_from_coordinates(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)  #get the distance
  new_column.append(value)   #append the empty list with distance values

df.insert(4,"Distance",new_column)  #4 is the index where you want to place your column. Column index starts with 0. "Distance" is the header and new_column are the values in the column.

with open(output_file,'ab') as f:
  df.to_csv(f,index = False)       #creates the output.csv
```

**The output:**

So, after going through the operation, the output.csv file is a separate file which contains all the previous 4 columns as well as the 5th column which is the distance. You can use a for loop to do this. The method that I am showing here reads each row and calculates the distance and append it in an empty list which is the new column "Distance" and eventually creates output.csv.

**The errors:**

```
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  To re-infer data dtypes for object columns, use DataFrame.infer_objects()
For all other conversions use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.
  after removing the cwd from sys.path.
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ce103283fa0d> in <module>
     33 
     34 with open(output_file,'ab') as f:
---> 35   df.to_csv(f,index = False)       #creates the output.csv

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
   3021 
   3022         if path_or_buf is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    170                 self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
    171 
--> 172             self._save()
    173 
    174         finally:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in _save(self)
    272     def _save(self):
    273 
--> 274         self._save_header()
    275 
    276         nrows = len(self.data_index)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in _save_header(self)
    240         if not has_mi_columns or has_aliases:
    241             encoded_labels += list(write_cols)
--> 242             writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
    243         else:
    244             # write out the mi

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

**Similar Problem:**

[Link to Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029396/using-pandas-to-calculate-distance-between-coordinates-from-imported-csv?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but why don't you just use `df = pd.read_csv(input_file, delim_whitespace=True)` without the following line that contains the `convert_objects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the following corrections:

instead of `df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)` put `df[:] = df[:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`

Also by `with open(output_file,'ab') as f:` you are opening the file in binary format, instead you should use `with open(output_file,'w') as f:`

then it should work.